# SqlException 'timeout expired' when executing nonquery, but data are inserted

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2012

I'm hitting weird behavior under load testing scenario: backend (sql server 2012) is getting overloaded and some of the commands times out (this is still expected as the backend server is half-intentionally slow HW); but our platform is regularly (with increasing delay) retrying the timeouted operation - and after few retries it suddenly starts receiving 'cannot insert duplicate key' SqlException.

I verified that only a single row with a specific unique key can be generated and is attempted to be inserted (first insert and all possible retries always happens on the same thread).

I also altered the SP so that it uses explicit transaction:

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- Insert into table A

    -- Insert into table B

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW
END CATCH
```

Yet the issue is still occurring.

Are there any ideas why this can be happening?

How can I find out where is the timeout coming from (backend vs. client side)?

Is there a way how to make sure that the operation either successful finishes or fails (basically transaction - but probably from client side code)?

**EDIT01:**
I believe one way of solving this is leverage of ado.net integration of SQL server distributed transactions - e.g:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    //Perform the sql commands

    //if above statements throws (e.g. due to timeout) - than the transaction is not commited and it will be rolled back
    scope.Complete()
}
```

HOWEVER: I agree that it only adds complexity and actuly might be still object to the same problem (Two Generals problem as outlined by usr).
The best approach therefore is likely to code client and server side to count on such an option - again as noted by usr in his answer

Comment: This may occur due to the command timeout in sql connection. So my suggestion is to try setting the CommandTimeOut value manually because it's default value is 30 seconds. also refer the below link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx

Comment: Please post how your code for identifying  and retrying the timedout operation.  If it is a sqlexception then it came from SQL.

Comment: @Blam - yes it is SqlException - but it still doesn't have to mean that it originates from the server, does it?

Comment: Look at the  call stack.   But I have never had a SqlException that was not a SQL exception.  I thought the timeout was actually returned from SQL.  Not the command giving up on SQL.  In SSMS there is a timeout setting.  Command giving up on SQL and just have SQL spin with no connection left to return results on would be a really  bad design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is expected behavior. When the communication between the client and the server is interrupted the client does not know the result of the operation. It might never have been sent, or it was sent but not received, or it was received but failed, or it was received but the success response did not come through.

This is the [Two Generals Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals'_Problem). It is unsolvable (when defining it strictly).

You must work around it. Either check for existence before insert or handle the duplicate key exception.

Or, simply increase the timeout. It does not do you any good to abort an otherwise working command that would have succeeded eventually. Aborting and restarting it does not make it go faster (except by coincidence). Timeouts are mostly useful for network errors or run-away queries (bugs).

Comment: very helpful answer. do you have any resource supporting the claim that this is unsolvable? I believe that sql should abort executed query if the connection is dropped from client side.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals'_Problem The server cannot find out the connection dropped. This is a symmetric problem. There is no possible exchange of messages such that both sides reliably come to the same conclusion. You'll find this in any distributed system. For example no message queue in the universe can prove exactly-one delivery.

Comment: But OP is saying they got SQLtimeout exception.  Loss of communication is not a SQLexception.

Comment: Query timeouts are caused by the client. ADO.NET sends an attention to the server when a timer expires. This is a client-side mechanism. The attention might not reach the server in time to cancel the query (or not reach it at all). In that case a timeout exception is observed, yet the query has completed.

Comment: @usr I polity don't agree.  Do you have documentation on that.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=VS.100).aspx  Per the documentation The exception that is thrown when SQL Server returns a warning or error.

Comment: When the client wants to cancel it can either report cancellation before receiving confirmation, or it can do it the other way around. In both cases client and server can become unsynchronized (the Generals Problem). There is no guaranteed safe way. In fact I know from experience that both network errors as well as timeouts lead to a SqlException (do you disagree?). Also, from the question it is apparent that the exception is raised before confirmation from the server arrives.

Comment: If we go on it will seem like I am argueing with you and that is not my intent.  I take SqlException to mean OP explicitly got a SqlExceptoin.

Comment: All of these errors lead to ex.GetType() == typeof(SqlException). Everything is wrapped. Regarding cancellation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/07/23/how-it-works-attention-attention-or-should-i-say-cancel-the-query-and-be-sure-to-process-your-results.aspx. (Do not hesitate to point out any mistakes you spot my in my answers. I can take it.)

Comment: I believe you +1 (a while ago).  If timeout was enforced at the serve side then I would expect to see it as a TSQL option (and I do not).

Answer (score -1):

Per the documentation [SqlException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=VS.100).aspx).

> The exception that is thrown when SQL Server returns a warning or
>   error. This class cannot be inherited.

My experience is that if you got a SQL exception then it came from SQL.

Timeout is a SQL setting.  You can set it SSMS.

OK I am now believe usr +1 that this comes from the client side 
[SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the wait time before terminating the attempt to execute a
>   command and generating an error.

That just is not how I would want it to be implemented. 
You could have a crazy query and lose connection SQL would just keep on running.

Comment: There are special error numbers for network and timeout conditions. I believe -2 is one of them. The documentation that is quoted here is wrong.; Timeout is a client-side setting. SSMS is a client, that's why it can be set there.

Comment: @usr Do you have evidence that come from the client.  I take "when SQL Server returns a warning or error" to mean exactly that.  Not that I don't believe you but you the documentation is wrong is not much.

Comment: Here's a better post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/support_sql_france/archive/2012/02/24/x-ray-of-sql-server-timeout-and-user-cancel.aspx The client sends cancellation which can be suppressed (as a test) by suspending the process.

Comment: @usr OK I will look into this some more.  I don't have a SQL server that is mine to "mess with" right now.  If it was initiated by the client I would still expect a SqlException timeout to be confirmed as as SqlExpeption and if it was a network to be reported a as a lost connection - but you don't always get what you expect.